Show Microphone and Camera Permission Pop-up in the Centre like Google Meet in Google Chrome
Google Meet has recently updated their UI (ref). As per the new UI, the microphone and camera permission pop-up (/ confirmation dialog) is prompted in the centre of the screen while dimming out the rest of the screen (image reference attached).

I would like to replicate the same, but I'm unable to find any documentation on the same.
How can I achieve that?
I tried using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() which opens the permission dialog in the top left corner.

Custom element in origin trial.
Ref: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/permission-element-origin-trial

this is a link only answer. You risk this answer to be downvoted or even deleted if you don't change this. To do so, edit your answer and add a better explanation what's behind the link. Links can grow stale over time. Since questions and answers are being archived for long time, providing only link is deprecated.
